# PHP algorithm for finding x in (x+1) mod 10 = 0

Tags: php, algorithm

Suppose I have the following series:

```
(x+1) mod 10 =0, (x+2) mod 10 = 0, (x+3) mod 10 = 0, .........,(x+11) mod 10 =0, (x+12) mod 10 = 0,........
```

I need a way to find the x. x+any number should be a number like 10, 20, 30, 40, 50....
For any help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lowest possible value for X

**a) X must be > 0:**

```
$x = 10 - ( $y % 10 )
```

Examples:

```
$y =  0   > $x = 10   (tot = 10)
$y =  1   > $x =  9   (tot = 10)
$y =  2   > $x =  8   (tot = 10)
$y = 10   > $x = 10   (tot = 20)
```

**b) X can be 0:**

```
$x = 10 * ( ($y % 10)>0 ) - ( $y % 10 )
```

Examples:

```
$y =  0   > $x =  0   (tot =  0)
$y =  1   > $x =  9   (tot = 10)
$y =  2   > $x =  8   (tot = 10)
$y = 10   > $x =  0   (tot = 10)
```

<kbd>**[PhpFiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hk0d-5qi8)**</kbd>

#### “Y Multiplication” value for X

```
$x = ( $y * 10 ) - $y
```

(Parentheses are not necessary)

Examples:

```
$y = 1   > $x =  9   (tot = 10)
$y = 2   > $x = 18   (tot = 20)
$y = 8   > $x = 72   (tot = 80)
```

<kbd>**[PhpFiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ftgy-zes7)**</kbd>

I think that code is self-explanatory...

Comment: Sorry If my question is not clear enough, but my main question is this that find the lowest possible value for x that if we sum that with y and then get mod 10 of that, then the reminder should be 0, suppose if y = 2 then for x the lowest possible value is 8 not 18, because `(8+2)  mod 10 = 0`.

Comment: @jones ok, I understand now.

Comment: @jones x can be 0? In other words, if y=10, x=0 or x=10?

Comment: @jones updated answer

Comment: If y = 10 then x can be 0 yeah